# me sale error [Error] no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'int')calcular la edad

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void){

    string nombre, segundonombre, primerapellido, segundoapellido, fecha;

 cout<<"Este Programa Te Dira Tu Nombre Completo"<<endl;
 cout<<"Porfavor ingresa Tu Primer Nombre: "<<endl ;
 cin>>nombre ; 
 cout<<"Porfavor ingresa Tu Segundo Nombre: "<<endl;
 cin>>segundonombre; 
 cout<< "Ahora Tus Apellidos: \n\n"<<endl;
 cout<<"Porfavor ingresa Tu Primer Apellido: "<<endl;
 cin>>primerapellido; 
 cout<<"Porfavor ingresa Tu Segundo Apellido: "<<endl;
 cin>>segundoapellido; 
  cout<<"Ingresa Su fecha de nacimiento: "<<endl;
 cin>>fecha; 
 cout<<"tu edad es: "<<endl;
 cin>>fecha-2017; 
 cout <<"Tu Te Llamas: "<<nombre<<"\n\n"<<segundonombre<<"\n\n"<<primerapellido<<"\n\n"<<segundoapellido<<"\n\n"<<fecha<<"\n\n"<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

su error esta en esta linea:

```
cin>>fecha-2017;
```

`fecha` es del tipo `string` al que usted esta tratando de restar un "int"

puede tratar lo siguiente para es error:

```
//..
cin>>fecha; //asignas el valor a fecha
fecha = std::to_string(std::stoi(fecha)-2017);
//..
```

[`std::stoi(fecha)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) combierte el parametro en un entero.

[`std::to_string(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) combierte el parametro en un string

Ahora ese `string` se le asigna a `fecha` con `fecha =...`

Comment: Según el código tengo `-18` xD (Lo tuyo esta perfecto la matematica del señor nope)

Comment: @HectorSeguro no me habia centrado en el resultado solo en el error, entre otras porque no se como introduce la fecha  pero si ese es el error trate -> `fecha = std::to_string(2017 - std::stoi(fecha)); `Saludos

Answer (score 2):

```
string fecha;

cout<<"Ingresa Su fecha de nacimiento: "<<endl;
cin>>fecha;
cout<<"tu edad es: "<<endl;
cin>>fecha-2017;
```

En la última linea tienes dos errores:

- fecha es de tipo `string`, que no admite operaciones aritméticas
- estás usando `cin` en vez de `cout`

Para solucionar el primer problema debes convertir la fecha en una representación numérica, de tal forma que sea posible realizar operaciones aritméticas con la misma. Para poder hacer esto antes tienes que tener claro que debes especificar cuál va a ser el formato esperado de la fecha:

- dd/mm/AAAA
- mm/dd/AAAA
- AAAA/mm/dd
- ??

Una vez hayas especificado el formato puedes empezar a procesar la fecha. Asumamos que has elegido la primera opción. Una forma simplona de acceder sería:

```
int ExtraerAnio(std:: string const& fecha)
{
  int dia,mes,anio;

  std::sscanf(fecha.c_str(), "%d/%d/%d", &dia, &mes, &anio) != 3)
  {
    // Error de parseo
  }

  return anio;
}
```

Con lo que tu código quedaría

```
cout<<"tu edad es: "<<endl;
cout>>ExtraerAnio(fecha)-2017;
```

El código podría mejorarse para que tuviese en cuenta si aún no has cumplido años o no teniendo en cuenta el día y el mes